# Remove event time from Angular ui-calendar event

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

Just a question here. I noticed that in my calendar, also the example given in the Ui Calendar page (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/), the event block has strange values on it (4p, 8p, 12a), in which after checking out, its actually represents the event time. I didn't provide any time in my event object (and so do the examples in the Ui calendar page too), but it still display that 4p 8p 12a values on the event block.

How can i remove that event time values if in my event object, i didn't specify any time value to it, and i only want to display title or probably leave it empty just like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [github docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar), it says that the component works with everything mentioned in the [fullcalendar.io documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/). From that page, the `displayEventTime` property certainly looks like it might do the trick. Perhaps something like:

```
// config object
calendar: {
    height: 450,
    editable: true,
    displayEventTime: false, 
    // etc...
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way to hide those elements.
AngularUI's use a CSS class to style event times, just hide it in your own CSS:

```
.fc-time {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: `.fc-event-time { display: none !important; }` did the trick for me. Thanks for the hint.